# How to pass data from node.js to html?

Tags: html, json, node.js

This is my nodejs

```
var http = require('http');   
var request = require("request");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
console.log("welcome");

request("https://cognitive/myurl/w1/monitor/mystatus", function(error, response, body) {
 console.log(body);
 var mydata = body;
});
```

How to pass this mydata to html? Mydata will contain JSON. I want to print table from that JSON. If it is app.get i can through ajax call. I'm new to nodejs, if anyone knows please help!

Comment: the best way to this solution is using ajax!
and another way is to use view engines.
see this : [mvc express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mvc-generator)

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass this mydata to html? Mydata will contain JSON. I want to
>   print table from that JSON. If it is app.get i can through ajax call.
>   I'm new to nodejs, if anyone knows please help!

Assuming you use [JQuery](https://jquery.com/). You'll need to attach an even handler to your HTML file that will trigger a $.get() request when it is triggered. Add your url to the data in your $.get call and do something with it.

```
$('.my_selector').click(function(){
   $.get('http://MY_SERVER_ADDR:MY_PORT/data', {}, function(data){
        console.log(data)
   });
});
```

From there you can insert your data anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make your server return JSON instead of the hardcoded string you currently have. Here's a tiny example to get you started:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  response.end (JSON.stringify ({ a: 'b' }))
}).listen(3000);
```

This creates a server that responds with the JSON representation of the hash { a: 'b' } when you send it a GET '/' request.

You can now do one of two things:

1. Look into a templating engine such as Pug, or HBS. Frameworks like Express are easy to configure with these out of the box. Configured correctly, you can generate views dynamically based on the data.
2. Write a separate front end for your application, that requests your JSON with AJAX calls. The simplest way of doing this is with jQuery.ajax, but there are full fledged front end frameworks that facilitate this sort of thing.

A simple front end application would look like:

```
$.getJSON ('localhost:3000/', function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (key, value) {
    $('#myList').append( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + value + "</li>" );
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. This should work to get your data from node server to a html page.

Make a AJAX request from webpage to the node server.

```
function getData (query) {
  query = query || '';
  url = 'http://localhost:3000';

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url + query);

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if(xhr.status === 200) resolve(xhr.responseText);

    else reject(Error(xhr.statusText + 'status : ' + xhr.status));
  }

    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error('Network Error'))
    }
   xhr.send();
  })
}


getData().then(function(response) {
  //do something with response
    });
```

at the node server:

```
var server = http.createServer().listen(3000);
server.on('request' , function (request, response) {

switch (request.method){
    case 'GET':
        handleGET(request, response);
    break;

    case 'POST':
        handlePOST(request, response);
    break;

    default:
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    break;
}

function handleGET (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    });
  res.write(JSON.stringify(result))
  res.end()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a templating engine in your NodeJS application such as EJS. With the help of EJS, you can send any type of data to your HTML file(in this case **.ejs** files) and render it according to your requirement.

Refer to this link for more information:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs